# Negating a string to be passed to mssql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a text field which acts a filter field. It checks for equals, contains and starts with. My problem is, with out changing any of my code, can I check for the 'does not contain', 'does not start with' and so on by just using the string i'm passing with something like '!' operator or "<>"?

for example:
I want to get all the records that do not have 'a' in them, so can I pass the string  as "!a" or "<>a" or something so that I can get the required records? (I know these two don't work cause I tried.)

Comment: really? no way i can send the negation of the string?

Comment: You are asking for SQL Injection. Don't try this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: The only place I can think of that has the concept of negative matches *embedded* within a string are languages where regular expressions are expressed as strings. T-SQL doesn't support regular expressions, and I'm not aware of any language that does support "negated strings" (that aren't a representation of a regex)

Comment: i'm not looking for an SQL injection, what i need is to use my existing code to do a different function, based on my input.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the keyword `NOT`, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Foo NOT LIKE '%bar%'
```

Comment: i don't want to change my query or any code for that matter. i want to change my input so that it satisfies the condition i need.

Comment: I don't think that's possible then.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1213442-338-1.aspx
Can solve with case in where clause